# Creating custom Operation for encapsulating some map algebra using GeoTools?

Tags: geotools, map-algebra

In GeoTools, I need to perform a one-to-one pixel computation between a bunch of GridCoverage2D. In short: some map algebra.
As I understood I can do things like summing values of coverages using:

```
Coverage summCoverage = Operations.DEFAULT.add(coverage1, coverage2);
```

I would like to create an Operation involving multiple coverages.. ..but I didn't find any hint about how to proceed.

Comment: please don't edit your question to add new questions - just ask a new question referencing this one

Comment: I have seen @geowolf demo ndvi calculation interactively - see http://blog.geoserver.org/2018/09/24/geoserver-2-14-0-released/ for an example

Comment: Nice suggestion indeed: I will study that reference as tha chance of calling Jiffle through an SLD was completely out of my sight!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need [`jiffle`](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/unsupported/process/process-raster.html) which is contained in the `gt-process-raster` module. Once you have constructed a Process you can pass in a list of source rasters and bands for it to process in the [execute method](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/process/raster/JiffleProcess.html#execute-org.geotools.coverage.grid.GridCoverage2D:A-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-it.geosolutions.jaiext.range.Range.DataType-org.opengis.util.ProgressListener-). The actual operation is defined in the [jiffle scripting language](https://github.com/geosolutions-it/jai-ext/wiki/Jiffle---language-summary) which is fairly powerful including loops, conditionals and good range of functions. You can also extend it if necessary.