# Summing mulitple GridCoverage Objects using GeoTools?

Tags: java, geotools, esri-ascii-raster

I'm working in Java and GeoTools to process some ASCII rasters. At present, I'm trying to get the rasters summed onto one large grid. I've tried a couple of methods but I seem to be having some performance degradation.

(These are manually copied so apologies for typos)

I initially tried:

```
Operatons op = new Operations(null);
GridCoverage2D sum = initialise();
for (GridCoverage2D grid : grid){
    sum = op.add(sum, grid);
}
```

This rattled through seemly quickly but when I try to access the sum it takes ages, so I assume these operations are conducted lazily. I then tried to add a writer in between to access the grid so it's calculated on the fly.

```
Operatons op = new Operations(null);
GridCoverage2D sum = initialise();
for (GridCoverage2D grid : grid){
    sum = op.add(sum, grid);
    GridCoverageWriter writer = new ArcGridWriter(File.createTempFile(...))
    writer.write(sum);
}
```

Which improved things a little. I then thought doing a recursive sum might help, but I'm getting continuously slower results still and hammering a single processor. Are there any ways of increasing the speed of these operations or am I approaching this in the wrong way?

The grids are approximately 4000x4000. At the moment summing 6 grids takes 5 minutes, 8 takes about 15, and 10 takes approaching half an hour. The grids are generated using a FORTRAN model that I don't have access to and there could be up to approaching 100 grids being added together. I have resampled the grids so they all fall in the same envelope. The only problem with the first approach is the runtime, but I was wondering if there would be a more efficient way of doing it.

Comment: how big are your girds? how many grids do you have? where did they come from? how are they laid out? what is wrong with the 1st approach?

Comment: Hi Ian, I've added a clarification paragraph to address your questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311960/creating-custom-operation-for-encapsulating-some-map-algebra-using-geotools

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways to do this, one with an `Op.add` as you have now and the other with Jiffle.

```
GridCoverage2D[] grids = new GridCoverage2D[nRasters];
    for (int k = 0; k < nRasters; k++) {
      WritableRaster raster2 = RasterFactory.createBandedRaster(java.awt.image.DataBuffer.TYPE_INT, w, h, 1, null);
      for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {// width...

        for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
          raster2.setSample(i, j, 0, k);
        }
      }
      grids[k] = gcf.create("name", raster2, referencedEnvelope);

    }

    Operations op = new Operations(null);
    float[][] zero = new float[w][h];
    for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
        zero[i][j] = 0.0f;
      }
    }

    long start = new Date().getTime();
    GridCoverage2D sum = gcf.create("name", zero, referencedEnvelope);
    for (GridCoverage2D grid : grids) {
      sum = (GridCoverage2D) op.add(sum, grid);
    }
    long mid = new Date().getTime();
    System.out.println("calc = " + (mid - start));

    String url = "sum.tif";
    File file = new File(url);
    GeoTiffWriter writer = new GeoTiffWriter(file);
    writer.write(sum, null);
    writer.dispose();
    long end = new Date().getTime();
    System.out.println("write = " + (end - mid));
    System.out.println("total = " + (end - start));
    org.geotools.process.Process jiffle = Processors.createProcess(new NameImpl("ras", "Jiffle"));
    Map<String, Object> inputs = new HashMap<>();

    String[] sourceNames = new String[nRasters];
    String letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    String script = "dest = ";
    for(int i = 0;i<nRasters;i++) {
      sourceNames[i] = letters.substring(i, i + 1);
      script += sourceNames[i] + " + ";
    }
    script = script.substring(0, script.length() - 3) + ";";

    System.out.println(script);
    inputs.put(JiffleProcess.IN_SOURCE_NAME, sourceNames);
    inputs.put(JiffleProcess.IN_COVERAGE, grids);
    inputs.put(JiffleProcess.IN_SCRIPT, script);
    start = new Date().getTime();
    Map<String, Object> output = jiffle.execute(inputs, null);
    GridCoverage2D result = (GridCoverage2D) output.get(JiffleProcess.OUT_RESULT);
    mid = new Date().getTime();
    System.out.println("calc = " + (mid - start));

    url = "sum2.tif";
    file = new File(url);
    writer = new GeoTiffWriter(file);
    writer.write(result, null);
    writer.dispose();
    end = new Date().getTime();
    System.out.println("write = " + (end - mid));
    System.out.println("total = " + (end - start));
```

I get faster results with `Op.add` (roughly 2x faster with 10 4kx4k grids). But on my machine it's of the order 5-10 seconds.

```
calc = 122 ms
write = 5331 ms
total = 5453 ms

calc = 7762 ms
write = 2574 ms
total = 10336 ms
```

**Update**

Oddly, (as you report) if your grids are not square `Op.add` is much slower. Results as before but `height = 4001` gives (while 4001x4001 is the same as before):

```
calc = 142 ms
write = 8,360,682 ms
total = 8,360,824 ms

calc = 7177 ms
write = 2802 ms
total = 9979 ms
```

So if you have "irregular" grids jiffle might be the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm not 100% sure, but it might be to do with my grid sizes. Running your example with h and w = 3000, I get comparable results. If I change them away from multiples of 10, ie 3000 and 3001, I get the hangups. I couldn't see anything in the documenation about this, so I'm starting to think its a bug. I notice you're a geotools developer, if you think I should raise a bug report I'm happy to do so.